# Custom query filter by ACF date custom field

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, request-filter

I'm using a custom query to filter posts by date range, i read the documentation and i searched for many examples, but this code seems right to me and i don't know why it is not working ! please help it's making me crasy :(

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // do not modify queries in the admin
    if( is_admin() ) {

        return $query;

    }


    // only modify queries for 'event' post type
    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'pubmed' ) {

        if( isset($_GET['date_deb'] ) && isset($_GET['date_fin'] )  ) {

            $date_debut = strtotime("01-01-".$_GET['date_deb']);
            $date_fin = strtotime("31-12-".$_GET['date_fin']);

            $date_debut = date('Ymd',$date_debut);
            $date_fin = date('Ymd',$date_fin);

            //echo $date_debut->format("Y");
            $query->set( 'meta_query' , array( 
                                            array(

                                                'key' => 'datecreated',
                                                'value'   => array( $date_debut , $date_fin ),
                                                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                                                'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                                            )
                        ));

        } 

    }

    // return
    return $query;

}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

Comment: PS: I'm filtering by "Year range" and then used a tweak to compare two dates instead (as it shows in my code).

Comment: I found out that my code is right, but it works only if i save the post manually from the backend, because i was importing posts from an xml file and saving custom fields with the ACF update_field() function, so it's not actually saving the custom field in the same way default wordpress custom fields works, so when i create a query with a custom field filter, it does not work because it's finding it empty field unless you save the post again manually.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the date format should be different - like:

```
        $date_debut = date('Y-m-d',$date_debut);
        $date_fin = date('Y-m-d',$date_fin);
```

I haven't tested this but the [doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) says:

> The 'type' DATE works with the 'compare' value BETWEEN only if the
>   date is stored at the format YYYY-MM-DD and tested with this format.

Comment: thaks for your response, but I found out that my code is right, but it works only if i save the post manually from the backend, because i was importing posts from an xml file and saving custom fields with the ACF update_field() function, so it's not actually saving the custom field in the same way default wordpress custom fields works, so when i create a query with a custom field filter, it does not work because it's finding it empty field unless you save the post again manually.